# How to stop re-orderring of the array elements when updating array elements in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am actually trying to change the quantity of the cart item , and every time i change , the whole product gets re-ordered by itself,

I am not able to figure out based on what the elements are being re-ordered.

How to stop this from happening?

Before Updating the quantity the cart items are as follows

[image]

After updating the quantity the cart items are as follows, The product gets reordered automatically.

[image]

My code for updating is  :

```
 void setQuantity(CartItemModel item, int quantity) {
    removeCartItem(item);
    item.quantity = quantity;
    item.cost = (int.parse(item.price!) * item.quantity!).toString();
    utilityController.updateUserData({
      'cart': FieldValue.arrayUnion([item.toJson()])
    });
  }
```

**It's because the array element is deleted and then added ,
But how to overcome this problem !!**

Comment: Arrays have a fixed order, it means when you delete an item from inside an array, items with greater index will change by -1. Instead of deleting item, just edit it.

Comment: How to edit ? in firebase doc it says theres no method to update an array element

Comment: Edit array you're working in your app. This array has the same indexes as the array in firebase. Every time you update whole array and problem is when you mix it on client side.

Comment: Do you have any examples ? because as of now , without arrayUnion and arrayRemove there's no any other way !

Comment: There is always other way! I'm not a Dart programmer, read documentation how you can update array.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore "arrays" are ABSOLUTELY NOT ARRAYS - they are "ordered lists" - the "number" is their order, not an index.  The ORDER of the entries *in* the object are important, as well, so:

```
{
id: "xxxxxx",
img: "xxxxx",
name: "xxxxx",
nameKa: "xxxxx"
}
```

WILL NOT MATCH

```
{
id: "xxxxxx",
name: "xxxxxx",
nameKa: "xxxxxx",
img: "xxxxxx",
}
```

Firestore's scale and speed come from indexing entries, and an "array" (ordered list) of objects is essentially indexed by a string-like representation of the object.

Firestore "arrays" (ordered lists) of *objects* are remarkably difficult to use, and give you *no* advantages - they  are much better suited to "single value" entries.  I would *strongly* recommend using a sub-collection of documents (each member in it's own document), where you can trivially query (either a a collection or collectionGroup) to find individual documents.